# Adding subviews dynamically into the main view on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I wanted to create a main view which consists of a add button.

On each click on the add button a subview must be added in the main view.the subview is present in another class which consists of a close button,on click of the close button  the subview class informs the main view through delegate function and the particular subview mist get removed from the main view.

The remaining subviews must be repositioned in the main view.

I want the subviews to be added in the main view in **matrix form(2xN)** matrix. That is 2 subviews in one rows and n number of columns.

I have implemented two methods for the same, but the subviews are not getting repositioned.

**method 1 :**

```
    - (IBAction)btnAddView:(id)sender
    {

        if ((count%2)==0)
        {
            NewSubView *subView = [[NewSubView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10+       (i*120), 100, 100) andDelegate:self];
           // [self.view addSubview:subView];
            [arr addObject:subView];
            i++;

        }
        else if ((count%2)==1)
        {
            NewSubView *subView = [[NewSubView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10+(j*120), 100, 100) andDelegate:self];
           // [self.view addSubview:subView];
            [arr addObject:subView];
            j++;
        }

         count = count+1; 

        for (int x=0; x<[arr count]; x++) {
            [self.view addSubview:[arr objectAtIndex:x]];
        }


    self.lblCount.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"count: %d",count];

}


//  the delegate function for deleting the view is as follows  


- (void) handleDelegate:(id)sender
{
    int deletedIndex;
    for (int val=0; val<[arr count]; val++) {
        if([[arr objectAtIndex:val] isEqual:sender])
            deletedIndex =val;
    }
    dupArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arr];
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:deletedIndex];
    [sender removeFromSuperview];
    count--;
    self.lblCount.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"count: %d",count];


    if ((deletedIndex%2)==0)
        i=deletedIndex/2;
    if ((deletedIndex%2)==1)
        j--;



}
```

**method 2:**

```
   - (IBAction)btnAddView:(id)sender
   {
     int modifiedColValue= 10+(colValue*120);

        if (modifiedColValue<320)
        {

            NewSubView *subView = [[NewSubView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rowValue, modifiedColValue, 100, 100) andDelegate:self];
            [arr addObject:subView];

            colValue++;
        }
        else if (modifiedColValue>320)
        {
            rowValue=10;
            [self btnAddView:sender];
            colValue++;
        }

        count++;
        for (int x=0; x<[arr count]; x++)
        {
            [self.view addSubview:[arr objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

    }
```

how can i reposition the remaining subviews,where count is the number of subviews, 320 is the width of the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is UICollectionView. You may find this tutorial helpful: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Comment: Hi,This was really a helpful tutorial but i want to do the same with UIView instead of collection view.any idea how to do that.
thank you for sharing this link..

Comment: Sorry for the late response! You can use drawRect: method to arrange children views. When you add/delete child view just invalidate parent by using setNeedsDisplay:.

Comment: You may also want to tweak you code further. You don't need another array to keep tracking of subviews because parent view is already doing this by using addSubview:. Just use subviews property of the parent view to access children views. You also don't need to add delegate methods for adding or removing views, just use didAddSubview: and willRemoveSubview: in parent. To remove child view just call [self removeFromSuperview] on button action.

Comment: hi,thanks for the response... willRemoveSubview is going to remove the subview from the main view.but how do i reposition the remaining views to the position from which the old view was removed.

Comment: In willRemoveSubview: loop via subviews. With every view after one to be removed do something like this: `self.subviews[i].frame = self.subviews[i-1].frame;`

Comment: thanks for the response.. i tried with this but the views are not getting repositioned.

Comment: This could be because you have Auto layout enabled. If this is the case you can disable it or set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES before changing the frame.